# Is TransactionScope in .NET applicable to only specific types of transactions?

Tags: c#, transactionscope

`TransactionScope` provides functionality to convert a set of operations into a transaction so that either all are completed successfully or none. My question is does transaction scope apply to certain types of operations (e.g. only SQL connnections, Azure, etc.)?

For example, consider the code block below

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    SaveToSQLserver(parameter);
    SaveToSalesForce(parameter);
    SaveToSAP(parameter);
    SaveToAzure(parameter);
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Now suppose an error occurs at `SaveToSAP`, where it has already saved to Salesforce; how is the transaction going to rollback from Salesforce? And if everything is in memory, then how is it going to make sure that when it actually saves it will succeed?

Comment: The commit and rollback functions are controlled by respective [Resource Managers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-a-resource-manager?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 2):

A `TransactionScope` is capable of supporting a distributed transaction across many different types of systems, but it is not an automatic thing. This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/enlisting-resources-as-participants-in-a-transaction) provides a glimpse into that (it's worth checking out the whole of the document hierarchy on [Transaction Processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/).

As mentioned by Dave Anderson in the comments, a Resource Manager controls what is done during commit and rollback, so the "how is it done" is governed individually by each resource manager.

So, can other things participate in a transaction scope besides just SQL? Yes, they can. As long as a Resource Manager exists for each system (e.g. a messaging system), it can participate ([enlist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/enlisting-resources-as-participants-in-a-transaction)).

If you are working with something that can't enlist, you have to manually do a [compensating transaction](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/architecture-center/blob/master/docs/patterns/compensating-transaction.md) when you detect you need to rollback (usually when an exception occurs).